# Generar datos con Factory laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de generar datos rondón para insertarlos con Factory, pero al momento de llamarlo en el archivo DatabaseSeeder me marca error, creo que lo estoy haciendo de la manera no adecuada

UserFactory

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'apellidos' => $this->faker->lastName(),
            'edad'=> $this->faker->numberBetween(5,60), 
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'password' => bcrypt('123456'), // password
            // 'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
```

DatabaseSeeder

```
factory(User::class)->times(40)->create(), //Aqui ya me muestra error. undefine function 'Database\Factories\UserFactory'
```

No se si estoy haciendo bien el llamado de userfactory en DatabaseSeeder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con laravel puedes crear factorias en memoria o guardarlas en BD,
con `->create()` **guardas en BD** con `->make()` **las creas en memoria**

```
User::factory()->count(40)->create();
User::factory()->count(40)->make();
```